# Change One Cell's Data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

How can I change the data in only one cell of a mysql table.
I have problem with UPDATE because it makes all the parameters in a column change but I want only one changed. How?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the query you are using? Usually, you do not update "all the parameters in a column"

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You probably need to specify which rows you want to update...

```
UPDATE 
    mytable
SET 
    column1 = value1,
    column2 = value2
WHERE 
    key_value = some_value;
```

Comment: I was confused by this answer, thinking SET selected rows to change, and WHERE changed them.

Comment: can the condition in WHERE be column1 = old_value ?

Comment: @weefwefwqg3, yes, it can, but there is no point. If you aren't changing the value, just leave it out of the SET part.

Comment: @Brian Hooper: I do need to change the value, I mean to ask whether I can do this: `UPDATE mytable SET column1 = new_value WHERE column1 = old_value;` ??

Comment: @weefwefwqg3, Ah, I see, sorry, an attack of myopia. Yes, that would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Would using "WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = 1;"  work to update just the first row of the table? (MySQL version 8)

Comment: @Calab, probably it would; haven't tried it. But be careful, as "the First Row in the Table" may not be well-defined.

Answer (score 119):

My answer is repeating what others have said before, but I thought I'd add an example, using `MySQL`, only because the previous answers were a little bit cryptic to me.

The general form of the command you need to use to update a single row's column:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column='new value' WHERE something='some value';
```

And here's an example.

**BEFORE**

```
mysql> select aet,port from ae;
+------------+-------+
| aet        | port  |
+------------+-------+
| DCM4CHEE01 | 11112 | 
| CDRECORD   | 10104 | 
+------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MAKING THE CHANGE**

```
mysql> update ae set port='10105' where aet='CDRECORD';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

**AFTER**

```
mysql> select aet,port from ae;
+------------+-------+
| aet        | port  |
+------------+-------+
| DCM4CHEE01 | 11112 | 
| CDRECORD   | 10105 | 
+------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for this demonstration. The above query will update all the instances of CDRECORD in your column aet. However, when updating a specific cell in a specific column, it is better to do that based on the ID of the column, i.e., where ID=xx

Comment: It is usually best to use the rows primary key, the rows unique identifier (which is often the ID, but not always). Honestly it depends on what you want to do which defines the "best" practice

Answer (score 31):

`UPDATE` will change only the columns you specifically list.

```
UPDATE some_table
SET field1='Value 1'
WHERE primary_key = 7;
```

The `WHERE` clause limits which rows are updated. Generally you'd use this to identify your table's primary key (or ID) value, so that you're updating only one row.

The `SET` clause tells MySQL which columns to update. You can list as many or as few columns as you'd like. Any that you do not list **will not** get updated.

Answer (score 11):

`UPDATE` only changes the values you specify:

```
UPDATE table SET cell='new_value' WHERE whatever='somevalue'
```

Answer (score 9):

Try the following:

```
UPDATE TableName SET ValueName=@parameterName WHERE
IdName=@ParameterIdName
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what does that `@parameterName`  do?

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE TABLE** `<tablename>` **SET** `<COLUMN=VALUE>` **WHERE** `<CONDITION>`

Example:

```
UPDATE TABLE teacher SET teacher_name='NSP' WHERE teacher_id='1'
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
UPDATE `database_name`.`table_name` SET `column_name`='value' WHERE `id`='1';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the columns in MySQL have an "on update" clause, see:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table_name;
```

I'm not sure how to update this but will post an edit when I find out.

Comment: If there is an "on update" it will be in the "Extra" column of the table you get when executing the above command.