# MySQL Update First Row In Table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, row

I have a table with single column.

**EmailTable**

| NotifyEmail |
| --- |
| mom@gmail.com |

No `id` no nothing just single row single column. So how do I update this row with new value?

I tried:

```
UPDATE NotifyEmail
FROM EmailTable
SET dad@gmail.com
```

It's not working.

edit, my table do not have ID. It's just a single column.

Comment: Please don't ask a question for something like this that is readily available via a google or the appropriate manual section.

Comment: @philipxy where in google can you solve my problem? If i have found in google or manual, i would'nt be asking in here. Pls refrain from commenting if you can't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change One Cell's Data in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024546/change-one-cells-data-in-mysql)

Comment: See [ask] & [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also [https://www.google.ca/search?q=So+how+do+I+update+this+row+with+new+value+mysql+stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.ca/search?q=So+how+do+I+update+this+row+with+new+value+mysql+stackoverflow.com). And [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: @philipxy the answer at "Change One Cell's Data in mysql " does not answer my question since my table is only one column without any ID. Pls read carefully my question before suggesting unrelated answers. Thank you.

Comment: Hm :\ I see all the answers there and not as clear as the one given here.Sorry to disapoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL [`UPDATE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement has the following syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

so, in your case, you should write the following query:

```
UPDATE EmailTable
SET NotifyEmail = 'dad@gmail.com'
WHERE NotifyEmail = 'mom@gmail.com';
```